# why parent view and child view are receiving onclickevent

Tags: android, handler

I have a parent view LinearLayout i have added a child view TextView, But whenever i click on childview why parentview is also clicked. What i want is to differentiate whether only parent has been clicked and only childview is clicked.

```
    LinearLayout rlmain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    rlmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

           }
    });

    TextView tv = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.TextViewLayout1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

           }
    });
```

Comment: setOnClickListener() method is not the same as overriding a view's OnTouchEvent() (or "OnClick") method. The callback passed into setOnClickListener gets called from within OnTouchEvent() (OnTouchEvent checks if mOnClickListener is not null and calls if it isn't), but still carries out it's functionality regardless (it doesn't return early if mOnClickListener is not null).

Answer (score 0):

then try to implement View.OnClickListener in yout Activity first, then try to override

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId().equals(R.id.linearLayout1) {
    //do ur stuffs
    } else {
    //do your stuffs
    }
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In android, ViewGroups (i.e. all layouts by inheritance) use the property (and corresponding xml attribute ) : [addStatesFromChildren](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3aaddStatesFromChildren)

If set, the parent will just be set in the very same state as one of his children view.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
LinearLayout rlmain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
rlmain.setOnClickListener(this);

TextView tv = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.TextViewLayout1);
tv.setOnClickListener(this)



@Override
public void onClick(View v){
  switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.TextViewLayout1:
    //do ur stuffs
    break;
    case R.id.linearLayout1:
    //do ur stuffs
    break;       
  }
}
```